# Why a resolve function nested in event callback never works?

Tags: javascript, promise, event-handling, puppeteer

I'm currently using puppeteer as a headless browser. The context is, when I login to the target website, it will navigate to 'https://poe.game.qq.com/my-account', so I use an event listener to listen to whether my login is successful. Here's a piece of my code:

```js
async function newBrowser(name, browsers) {
    /**
    * Start a browser...
    */

    const loginPage = browser.newPage(); 
    await loginPage.goto('some url');
    console.log('Waiting for login...');

    const loginPromise = new Promise( resolve => {
        loginPage.on('load', () => {
            if (loginPage.url()=='https://poe.game.qq.com/my-account') {
                console.log('Login successful.');
                resolve;
            }
        });
    });

    await loginPromise;
}
```

The fact is that my console actually prints out "Login successful." but the `loginPromise` is never resolved so my function `newBrowser` is always pending. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually call it with `resolve();`, not just `resolve;`.  It's a function - you have to call it.

And, you don't show where you're trying to look at the resulting promise either, but you'll have to wait until it's resolved to look at it because you attempt to look at the promise, otherwise, it will still be pending.  Note `newBrowser()` will return a pending promise when your code hits `await logionPromise` so, you can't just be immediately looking at the promise returned from `newBrowser()`.  Instead, you'd have to do `await newBrowser()` or `newBrowser().then(...)` to know when it is actually fulfilled.

Comment: Now I can tell I'm so fatigue that I cannot distinguish such a stupid problem for about one hour... Thanks!

Comment: @Vector - Yeah - welcome to the world of programming.  Happens to all of us - even to veterans.

Comment: Yeah I indeed used `await newBrowser()` when I'm try to look at it. By the way, is there any difference between ending my `newBrowser` function with `await loginPromise` and `return loginPromise` when I do not want to save the return value? I've tried both but their results seems to be the same.

Comment: @Vector - There is no reason to use `await` on the last line of a function as it is better to just return the promise directly.  You use `await` in the function if you want to run code in that function after the promise resolves or you're trying to catch the rejection with `try/catch`.  Otherwise, just return the promise back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to call the resolve callback in the function as resolve()

```
async function newBrowser(name, browsers) {
    /**
    * Start a browser...
    */

    const loginPage = browser.newPage(); 
    await loginPage.goto('some url');
    console.log('Waiting for login...');

    const loginPromise = new Promise( resolve => {
        loginPage.on('load', () => {
            if (loginPage.url()=='https://poe.game.qq.com/my-account') {
                console.log('Login successful.');
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });

    await loginPromise;
}
```